Laravel Sail - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
Anyone knows why this query is returning error? I'm using Laravel Sail with Mysql version: 8.0.32, it should work:
Property::select(DB::raw("
            properties.id,
            properties.company_id,
            properties.title,
            properties.slug,
            properties.neighborhood,
            properties.city,
            properties.address,
            properties.number,
            properties.property_purpose,
            properties.property_type,
            properties.total_area,
            properties.usefull_area,
            properties.bedrooms,
            properties.bathrooms,
            properties.garage,
            properties.sell,
            properties.rent,
            properties.administration_fee,
            properties.yearly_tax,
            property_highliteds.hightlight,
            companies.property_show_number,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY properties.company_id ORDER BY property_highliteds.hightlight DESC, properties.created_at DESC) as row_number
        "))
            ->leftJoin('property_highliteds', 'properties.id', '=', 'property_highliteds.property_id') // Relacionamento com os destaques
            ->leftJoin('companies', 'properties.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')   // Relacionamento com as empresas
            ->orderBy('row_number')  // Ordena pela intercalação dos imóveis
            ->with([
                'images_thumb:id,property_id,url',  // Carrega apenas a URL das imagens
                'company:id,property_show_number',  // Carrega o campo necessário de Company
                'highlight:id,property_id,hightlight' // Carrega o destaque via BelongsTo
            ])
            ->paginate($perPage);

And the error is:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC) as row_number from `properties` left join `companies` on `propert' at line 23

Tryed almost anything with ChatGpt and google search. My mysql is correct.

What is the query this generates? Can you determine from the MySQL logs? At first glance it seems to me that you are missing DB::table('some_table_name') at the start and thusly your query might end up lacking a from clause. But This is just a wild guess at this point.

Did the error message give you the full SQL query? You might want to try replacing ->paginate($perPage) with toSql(), and log the results to get the full query.

When using the ROW_NUMBER() function in SQL, you cannot directly use the alias (like row_number) in the ORDER BY clause of your main query. Instead, you must order by the actual columns that were used to create that row number.
Use :
orderBy(DB::raw("property_highliteds.hightlight DESC, properties.created_at DESC"))

